# Getting TypeScript to warn if array index may not be available

Tags: typescript

I'm using the `--strict` compiler option, but when accessing `savedEvent`, it doesn't warn me that it may be `undefined`:

```
tableService.queryEntities<EventSchema>(eventTableName, query, <any> null, {autoResolveProperties: true}, (error, result, response) => {
    if (error) {
        context.log.error(`Attempting to remove event. Could not find event with id: ${id}. Err: `, error);
        return;
    }

    // savedEvent can be undefined here since result.entries can be empty
    let savedEvent = result.entries[0];
}
```

How do I get it to warn me?

Comment: That's a *value* problem, not a *type* problem; it's not something the TS compiler can tell you about.

Comment: @jonrsharpe a type is a domain of values; it would be entirely possible to warn on this, TS just chooses not to

Answer (score 0):

[TypeScript assumes array access is in bounds](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13778); there is no compiler option to change this.

`--alwaysStrict` has to do with emitting a `"use strict";` directive at the top of output files; this will not change type checking. You might want `--strict` if you're looking for the least-lenient set of typechecking rules.

Comment: OP had originally said he's using the "strict" option, but I mistakenly edited it to "alwaysStrict". Changed it back now

Answer (score 0):

Follow up to previous answer, may be fixed by `noUncheckedIndexedAccess` in typescript 4.1 (released 2020)